# FirebaseProjectNotFoundException: Firebase project id could not be found on this Firebase account

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I found [this](https://github.com/pdichone/diary_webapp_course/tree/main/diary_webapp) project. After I added to `index.html` file the following Firebase configuration:

```
 <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js";
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-storage.js";

    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDoO8efzrDVveeXvqqrc39D3XiqfsyoKeU",
      authDomain: "diary-app-course-c6663.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "diary-app-course-c6663",
      storageBucket: "diary-app-course-c6663.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1031493909898",
      appId: "1:1031493909898:web:3cd71413645447b67c1c73"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
```

Next, I did the following steps on command line:

```
$ dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

$ vim ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc

$ flutterfire configure
$ curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
$ flutterfire configure
i Found 1 Firebase projects. Selecting project diary-app-course.
FirebaseProjectNotFoundException: Firebase project id "diary-app-course" could not be found on this Firebase account.
$ grep -R diary-app-course *
web/index.html:      authDomain: "diary-app-course-c6663.firebaseapp.com",
web/index.html:      projectId: "diary-app-course-c6663",
web/index.html:      storageBucket: "diary-app-course-c6663.appspot.com",
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 10):

Follow these steps:

1. Remove if their any default project exists in .firebaserc file.
   **Before:**

```
    {
      "projects": {
       "default": "diary-app-course"
      }
    }
```

**After**

```
    {
          "projects": {
          }
        }
```

2. Run this command in Firebase CLI:

```
firebase logout
```

3. Log in again:

```
firebase login
```

4. Again run this command in Firebase CLI

```
flutterfire configure
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
flutterfire configure --project=diary-app-course-c6663
```

You could see your project id on your firebase link
for example : https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/ *this is your project id*/database/xxxx/data

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that this firebase project is really connected to your account, and you are already logged in.
You can try to edit .firebaserc file
and change
"default": "**your project name**"
to
"default": "**your project id**"
then run: flutterfire configure

Answer (score -1):

So, I made some change: If you are trying to logging in one account for registering firebase while creating new project, and at that time but if your android studio account was another one it will be problem.

Make sure to use one gmail account for registering new project and login that entered project

[LOG OUT and LOG IN again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCFw1.png)
Please choose default account and create